# Linear Transformation or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$$T(x) = 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\
\sin \theta &  \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} 
\right]
\cdot
\left[ 
\begin{array}{c} 
x \\ y \\ 1
\end{array} 
\right]
$$

You have to solve it by definition: 
$$T(w_{1}) + T(w_{2}) = T(w_{1} + w_{2}),$$       and 
$$\alpha T(x) = T(\alpha x).$$

I am new here, I do not know the format, I’m sorry for any inconvenience that this may cause. Just wondering if the exercise above is a linear transformation or not.

Comment: Hint: see if $T(x+y)$ is... (do the same for the other part of the definition)

Comment: Is $\theta$ constant, or does it depend on $x$ and $y$? Is $y$ constant, or does it depend on $x$ and $\theta$?

Comment: θ Is constant, π/4 to be precise

Comment: You are supposed to solve it using the definition:   T(w1) + T(w2) = T(w1 + w2) and αT(x) = T(αx)

Comment: My first impression is that **It depends**. From what you have jotted down it looks like an affine transformation of the plane is being attempted. And among those this is certainly a linear transformation (because the translation component vanishes). But, if this is to be viewed as a transformation on three space restricted to the plane with third coordinate equal to one... Headache. You need to describe a bit of context to make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

$ L : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ is a linear transformation if and only if there is a matrix, $ A $, such that $ L( z ) = A z $...  What you have here is sort of like that...  BUT...

But here $L$ is a bit tricky:  it is a function of two variables.  Another thing you know about a linear transformation is that it should map the zero vector to the zero vector.  What happens if you pick $ x = y = 0 $?